# How do you move a website from localhost to server without changing much?

Tags: php, html, xampp, localhost

For example in my website I have so many links say

> "http//localhost/website/admin.php"

Which I want to be

> "http://website.com/admin.php"

For now, I just use replace command in editor but it takes long time to figure out. But i was thinking `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` could solve this problem. But it did not either. 
So how do you move your files from loalhost to server without changing anything?
 And I am not talking about wordpress site here. Its the one I created myself.

Comment: Start using PHPStorm and her magical powers ;). https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: thanks . i will for sure now. but can you please tell me whats so special about it

Comment: Why do you have so much absolute links on your site? Could you replace the moving parts through a variable?

Comment: As long as you haven't embedded the URL 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' in your URL's and used relative references then moving is trival.  If you have used absolute references then you need to change these to relative or correct the references to the address of your server.

Comment: is it good idea to save site name in database and change when moving?

Comment: Nah, just leave the database as it is. Look at my answer, that will be your solution for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you could make a `defines.php` file and include it in your `index.php`. What you could add is this: `define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));`

This means when you enter for example this: `$this->basePath =  BASE_PATH . '/lib/company/Layouts/';` you will always have the right base_path incase you switch servers.

I suggest to use PHPStorm: www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm. Read the documentations to learn about the possiblities. You can for example press `CTRL + R` and search for 'localhost'. Now you receive a display so you can edit ALL localhost with another input. But there are many more functions. PHPStorm is a **must-to-have**.

Somehow you still need to edit your files only once and the `defines.php` could be the solution for your next projects or in future current project.

I hope this helped you.